# how to configure mpm worker module in centos 6?

Tags: apache, multiprocessing, httpd.conf, apache-config

I search on the internet and I found that you have to set your changes in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` And I did but It still with the last configuration when I show it in the global configuration in Cpanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the main configuration in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` was been overridden by the config file in `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf` which is shown also in global configuration in Cpanel.